# Store the cursor position relative to surrounding text, make edits, then insert text at the stored location

Tags: point, marker

I have some insert functions that take some time (e.g., doing network IO). I like to store the current point position, and then insert the text at the stored point.

This should be robust to some small edits. I think `bookmarks.el` already has such a 'fuzzy' point storing machinery, but I am not sure if it's the best way to do this (or how to use `bookmarks.el`'s presumably private API).

Comment: See "Markers" in the Emacs Lisp manual. Do `C-h ig(elisp)Markers`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description, you don't want to return to a particular *buffer* position.  You want to return to a particular *text* position, that is, a position in *context*, a position relative to the text surrounding the original position.

As @NickD suggested in a comment, what you want to do is to create and store a **marker** at the original location.  Markers move along with the surrounding text.

```lisp
(let ((opt  (point-marker)))
  ;; DO STUFF
  (goto-char opt))
```

Read about markers in the Elisp manual, node [Markers](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Markers.html).

Comment: `(point-marker)`. `(make-marker)` doesn't accept arguments and creates an empty marker.

Comment: @HappyFace: Oops! Duh, 100% right. Thx - fixed.